# CSS select only one item from table

Tags: css, css-tables

Is there a way to disable multi-selection from a table in CSS?
I have a table, and the user can select multiple items but I want it to restrict it to one item, is there a way to do that through CSS?

Comment: select as in highlighting text?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer: there was possibly going to be a way, but no, there isn't.

Long answer: [one of the proposed values for `user-select`](http://www.w3.org/TR/2000/WD-css3-userint-20000216#user-select) was `element`. If the property made (or makes...) it into CSS3, I think that'd be the style you'd use. No browser implements it per the proposal though, since it was nothing beyond an idea. Vendor implementations usually only have `all`, `text` and `none` to choose from, but not `element` or `elements`.

Answer (score 0):

CSS does not control user selections.

The best you can do is put a transparent DIV over top of the area to prevent users from selecting it. They could also just use Firebug to delete this DIV.